# How do I get my java classpath to work using the commandline and shell scripts?

Tags: java, terminal, jar, jackson

I am trying to use `jackson-databind`'s `ObjectMapper` (without using maven) but cannot integrate the corresponding `ObjectMapper` class into my program.

My file structure:

```
 .
├──  First.class
├──  First.java
├──  jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar
├──  run.sh
└──  this.json
```

**First.java**:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

**run.sh**:

```bash
echo "Compiling..."
javac -cp "./jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar" First.java
echo "Compiled."
echo "----------------"
echo "Output:"
java First
```

I get the following error:

```py
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
        at First.main(First.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 1 more
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help

#### UPDATE

I changed the **`run.sh`** file to this:

```bash
echo "Compiling..."
javac -cp ".:./jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar" First.java
echo "Compiled."
echo "----------------"
echo "Output:"
java -cp ".:./jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar" First
```

and got the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/Versioned
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at First.main(First.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same classpath at runtime, except, you now need to find `First` as well.

Thus:

`java -cp ".:./jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar" First`

`.` = current dir (so that `First.class` will be found when resolving fully qualified classname `First`.

`:` separates classpath entries

`./jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar` which will mean that resolving fqn `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` will find the right class.

Comment: I get a different error now: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/Versioned` what does this mean?

Comment: That just the `databind` jar isn't sufficient. You need at least `jackson-core` jar as well.

Comment: Yup, by adding the extra required dependencies (`jackson-core` and `jackson-annotations`), it started working properly. Thank you!